# How to generate json by comparing both array(date) and array of objects?

Tags: arrays, json, date, for-loop

I want to compare array and array of objects in node.js and generate a new json objects based on comparing.
In the below code i am having **"dateList"** list of date and **result** having array of json, Now i want to compare both dateList and result, if result object having the date of dateList then we have to get the executions value and push into new array if not equal then we have to push as 0.

Server code:

```js
var dateList = [
  "2018-08-01",
  "2018-07-31",
  "2018-07-30",
  "2018-07-29",
  "2018-07-28",
  "2018-07-27",
  "2018-07-26"
]
var result = [{
    CDate: '2018-07-31',
    executions: 1
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-30',
    executions: 2
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-27',
    executions: 3
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-26',
    executions: 2
  }
];
var allList = [];

for (key in dateList) {
  for (keyResult in result) {
    if (dateList[key] === result[keyResult].CDate) {
      var obj = {
        "date": dateList[key],
        "value": result[keyResult].executions
      }
      allList.push(obj);
      break;
    } else {
      var obj = {
        "date": dateList[key],
        "value": 0
      }
      allList.push(obj)
      break;

    }
  }

}
console.log(allList);
```

Current Output:

```js
[{
    "date": "2018-08-01",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-31",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-30",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-29",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-28",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-27",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-26",
    "value": 0
  }
]
```

Expected Output:

```js
[{
    "date": "2018-08-01",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-31",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-30",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-29",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-28",
    "value": 0
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-27",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-26",
    "value": 2
  }
]
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `else` branch is inside the inner array, however you want to push a `0-entry` only if the inner loop has not found the given date in `result`, which you only know when the loop is over (new variable `found` tracks it):

```js
var dateList = [
  "2018-08-01",
  "2018-07-31",
  "2018-07-30",
  "2018-07-29",
  "2018-07-28",
  "2018-07-27",
  "2018-07-26"
]
var result = [{
    CDate: '2018-07-31',
    executions: 1
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-30',
    executions: 2
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-27',
    executions: 3
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-26',
    executions: 2
  }
];
var allList = [];

for (key in dateList) {
  var found=false;
  for (keyResult in result) {
    if (dateList[key] === result[keyResult].CDate) {
      var obj = {
        "date": dateList[key],
        "value": result[keyResult].executions
      }
      allList.push(obj);
      found=true;
      break;
    }// else {
  }
  if(!found){
    var obj = {
      "date": dateList[key],
      "value": 0
    }
    allList.push(obj)
    //break;
  }
}
console.log(allList);
```

An alternative approach would be creating a `0-entry` at the beginning an updating it from the inner loop and push at the end:

```js
var dateList = [
  "2018-08-01",
  "2018-07-31",
  "2018-07-30",
  "2018-07-29",
  "2018-07-28",
  "2018-07-27",
  "2018-07-26"
]
var result = [{
    CDate: '2018-07-31',
    executions: 1
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-30',
    executions: 2
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-27',
    executions: 3
  },
  {
    CDate: '2018-07-26',
    executions: 2
  }
];
var allList = [];

for (key in dateList) {
  var obj = {
    "date": dateList[key],
    "value": 0
  };
  for (keyResult in result) {
    if (dateList[key] === result[keyResult].CDate) {
      obj.value=result[keyResult].executions;
      break;
    }
  }
  allList.push(obj)
}
console.log(allList)
```

Comment: Above two methods working fine,In second method logic very nice.Thanks.:)